# $A_1 ∩ A_2 · · · ∩ A_n $is the set of all objects that are in all of the $A_j $’s

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

"For $n$ sets $A_1 , . . . , A_n$ , the union $A_1 ∪ A_2  · · · ∪ A_n$ is the set of all objects that are in at least one of the $A_j$ ’s, while the intersection $A_1 ∩ A_2 · · · ∩ A_n$ is the set of all objects that are in all of the $A_j$’s."

could somebody kindly help me understand the second part of the sentence "while the intersection $A_1 ∩ A_2 · · · ∩ A_n$ is the set of all objects that are in all of the $A_j$ ’s".

the first part which says that all objects that are in at least one of $A_j$ is easier to understand since $A_j$ is part of of the union set. however, all objects in the intersection set are in all of the $A_j$’s is confusing and i can't figure out a venn diagram to represent it.

Kindly advise. Thank you

Comment: @Henry, thank you for the reply. i understand how the three circles works. however, the second part of the sentence says all objects in the intersection set are in all of $A_j$ sounds confusing as it like saying that $A_j$  is all the intersections

Comment: There is definite problem in using Venn's diagram, because we cannot put 4 circles in plane in such a way, that they form 16 areas.

Comment: If you find it easier, then all elements of the intersection are elements of each of the $A_j$.  The intersection is a subset of each of the $A_j$ for $j\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$; indeed it is the largest such set which is a  subset of each of the $A_j$

Comment: @Henry, thanks this clears up the confusion of $A_j$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu  You can have four sets in a Venn diagram, but they may not all be circles.  That should not matter much, as this is not really about Euclidean geometry

Comment: I said about limited possibilities of Venn's diagram for representation. I believe that even when sets are not circles but interiors of closed curves, there will be limitation on sets count.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu [Try this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hI1q.png) for $5$ sets , easily extended

Comment: @Henry, may i ask what you used to draw your venn diagrams, it  seems to be more robust than matplotlib.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon Microsoft Paint - I am old (and old-fashioned)

Comment: your drew them manually?! omg.. really appreciate that you took the time drawing them out! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the classic Venn diagram of three circles, the union is the set of all the elements in *any* of the circles,

**Union:**

[image: Union]

while the intersection is the set of all the elements in *all* of the circles i.e. the most central part of the Venn diagram

**Intersection:**

[image: Intersection]

Comment: thank you providing the venn diagram, it makes it easier to reference. How do one represent $A_j$ in your diagram?

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon In my second diagram the pink area is $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 = \bigcap\limits_{j=1}^3 A_j$.  You could say it is $\{a: \forall j: \, a\in A_j\}$

Comment: Similarly in the first diagram the purple area is $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^3 A_j$ and you could say it is $\{a: \exists j: \, a\in A_j\}$

Comment: the purple area  can also be represented as $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3=A_1+A_2+A_3 -A_1\cap A_2-A_1\cap A_3-A_2\cap A_3+A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3$ right?

Comment: The use of $+$ and $-$ would need definition when applied to sets.  But if the sets are finite and you are counting elements, or if you are applying a measure,  then $|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3|=|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3| -|A_1\cap A_2|-|A_1\cap A_3|-|A_2\cap A_3|+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|$ makes sense and is based on inclusion-exclusion